# Execute Stored Procedure in Entity Framework doesn't return data

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server, this procedure returns a resultset with data, or 
an error message.

I have a view model, with the fields that stored procedure retrieves in the resultset, and I am executing the procedure like the next instruction

```
IEnumerable<StateVM> states= context.Database.SqlQuery<StateVM>(
                "Calculate_State_1  {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}",
                _from, _to, 8, 'Type1, Id1, Id2, StrError);
```

When I executed the query with the parameters in SQL, they are data, but in Entity Framework "states" return something related to the specified conversion from type System.String materialized to  System.Int32 are not valid.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not following this: `something relationed with the specified conversion from type System.String materialized to System.Int32 are not valid`.  Post the error message exactly as you are receiving it.

Comment: Code-First? Database-First? What does your stored procedure look like?

Comment: Call me old fashioned but when it comes to calling stored procedures I  ditch EF and go back to ADO.Net (which is what EF uses under the covers anyway). Yes it is more work but it pays off because it is very well documented and you don't have to deal with things like this.

Comment: This is the error, sorry, I have VS in spanish, and type here the error in spanish, if that is usefull, I do, but, translateddd, this is the error..

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your error message exactly, but it seems your procedure results in text in for a collumn that is and integer in the StateVM class so EF can't do this conversion.

Check for nulls, empty strings and trailing white spaces in your resultset

Comment: I try something, I rewrite the VM with a single property, one of the fields that SP returns and I know that fields are and String, and the error persist.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to bring over your stored procedures the same way you do your tables and execute them like a method call.

Comment: How can I do this???...Adding store procedure, and creating importing function, etc, etc... ????

Comment: If you're allowing VS to create your data model either check the box next to stored procedures or create a sql connection in server explorer and drag your stored procs onto your model. Or simply open your .dbml/.edmx file then drag your objects onto your model.

Answer (score -1):

Consider not using EF for your stored procedure calls and instead use ADO.Net. It is very well documented and any issues you run into are bound to be solved many times over.

[ADO.Net Using Stored Procedures](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson07)